# Datetime DATE DIFF not working as expected

Tags: mysql

I have a field `date_confirmed` which is a `datetime`.

So an example of the contents would be

> 2011-01-03 20:54:41

The where clause I built to extract recent rows from this table based on the `date_confirmed` is as follows...

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(g.date_confirmed, CURDATE()) <= 28
```

I am using PHP with MySQL and I want to only extract rows where the date in `date_confirmed` is less than 28 days.

Can someone help me / points me in a better direction?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem you're having? Your use of `DATEDIFF()` is correct. If you're getting a negative result, reverse the arguments or wrap it in `ABS()` for the absolute value

Comment: What a donut, didn't say what the issue was. It is displaying rows that are more than 28 days old.

Comment: Or try this - WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), g.date_confirmed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you don't say what's not working, but I think you might have meant to switch the parameters around:

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), g.date_confirmed) <= 28
```

as you had it, `CURDATE()` would (I assume) always be more recent than `g.date_confirmed` nd therefore `DATEDIFF()` would alwys return a negative number - and therefore always be `<= 28`

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want to change to:

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(g.date_confirmed, CURDATE()) <= -28
```

According to the documentation here (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) if the second argument is more recent than the first argument, the resulting number will be negative. Since I'm assuming that the current date is more recent than your stored date, I'm guessing that's what is happening here.

Comment: This didn't work but when I changed the parameters around, it did work. Thanks.

Comment: I think you mean >= -28, which would also work -- but swapping the arguments is clearer!

Answer (score 0):

I always find it clearer to write this as

```
WHERE g.date_confirmed >= DATE_SUB( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 28 DAY )
```

...especially where my record might have several date columns, I think this makes it clearer just which date field I'm comparing against.